# Linq (left join) and Sql

Tags: linq

```
SELECT  
    SI_2.[StudGUID] ,SI_2.[ClassName],
    SI_2.[StudGUID],SI_1.[StuName],SI_1.[Title],SI_1.[StuMobileNumber]
FROM 
    [StudentInfo2] AS SI_2
INNER JOIN 
    [StudentInfo] AS SI_1 ON SI_2.[StudGUID]=SI_1.[StuCode]
WHERE
    SI_2.[ClassID] IN (SELECT SC.[ClassID] 
                       FROM [SchoolClass] AS SC 
                       LEFT JOIN [BookClass] AS BC ON SC.[ClassID]=BC.[ClassID]
                       WHERE BC.[ClassID] IS NULL AND SchoolYear = 2015)
  AND SI_2.[isMonitor] = 1
```

Question: I want use Linq to implement the code in SQL. How to use Linq to implement the code?

Seek help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq left-joining like tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658471/linq-left-joining-like-tables)

Comment: Can you say it in detail? I don't know what to do.